# For UK immigration what it is considered a "reasonable journey"?

Tags: uk, transit

I am travelling to Dubai from Colombia, and I need to stopover UK. I saw that they allow me transit without a visa if I have a US visa and I am travelling "as part of a reasonable journey" to the US.

Now, I am wondering if buying a ticket leaving from Dubai after say 2 weeks to the US, would qualify as a reasonable journey?

Comment: So your itinerary is Colombia to UK to Dubai, where you will stay for two weeks?  To me, that is clearly not a journey to the US; it's a journey to Dubai.  If you're flying from Dubai to the US two weeks later, that seems like a separate journey.

Comment: And if your primary goal were really to get from Colombia to the US, getting there via the UK and Dubai with a two-week stopover would clearly not be a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: Well, I am going for a conference in Dubai and then on I need to go to the US. It can be earlier, say the day after I arrive in Dubai... but the jetlag would be beyond insane.

Comment: You asked specifically about going from Dubai to the US, but it certainly is not reasonable to go from Colombia to the US via the UK then Dubai. Those would be treated as separate journeys.

Comment: What you can persuade UK immigration of is irrelevant for practical purposes. The airline will see you as travelling to Dubai via London, and if you need a transit visa for that trip and don't have one, **they'll not let you on the plane!**

Answer (score 3):

"Reasonable" in this context means that it makes sense to transit the UK on your given itinerary.

For instance, transiting the UK between Dubai and the US is a little odd given the large number of direct flights, but it could be reasonable if you found cheap tickets.

An unreasonable journey would be one in which transiting the UK makes no sense at all, such as flying from Dubai to Bahrain.

Comment: Do you know if on that context, my arrival in Dubai and then leaving to the US later would still constitute a reasonable journey? I mean, do they consider the condition of transit without visa even if my flight to the US is booked but for a later date than my arrival in Dubai?

Comment: @Joe That depends on why your Dubai-US itinerary transits the UK, I suppose.

Comment: Ok, so it is possible that the days between my arrival in Dubai and when I leave to the US, might not be an issue?

Comment: @Joe I don't see any problem with going from Dubai to the US via the UK.

Comment: Thank you @michael. Let's hope UK immigration is as understanding.

Comment: @Joe the amount of time you spend in Dubai is *what makes the.journey reasonable.*  The context of the requirement will be a journey from Dubai to the US, and the thing that must be reasonable is stopping in London on your way from Dubai to the US.  That *is* reasonable, so you're all set.  If you were flying directly from Colombia to Dubai to London to the US, *that* would be weird, and risk triggering suspicion that the journey is unreasonable or, worse, that you want to stay in the UK illegally or to seek asylum there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Your answer is completely accurate in everything it says, but I think it rather misses the mark of the OP's proposal. The OP is proposing to fly Colombia-UK-Dubai, then have a two week holiday, then fly Dubai-US. As such, when he passes through the UK he will not be transiting the UK from Dubai to the US, he will actually be transiting the UK from Colombia to Dubai. The transit in the UK will therefore not be part of "a reasonable journey to the US".

Comment: "flying from Dubai to Bahrain" is quite irrelevant as this is about the meaning of a reasonable journey to the US".

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Dubai->UK->Bahrain would not be a reasonably journey to Bahrain.

Comment: I agree, but it would also not bring anybody to the US.

Comment: @AndyT You're quite right; that would not be reasonable. The question as originally written, though, asked about whether the Dubai-US itinerary was reasonable, not the Colombia-Dubai itinerary.